# In SugarCRM SOAP API, How to get all possible values of Opportunity status enum?

Tags: sugarcrm

Is there an API call to get all  possible values of Opportunity status/stagename enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's code to do it via REST, which should translate pretty much directly over to SOAP as well.

```
$parameters = array(
    'session' => $sessionId,
    'module_name' => 'Opportunities',
    );
$json = json_encode($parameters);
$postArgs = array(
                'method' => 'get_module_fields',
                'input_type' => 'JSON',
                'response_type' => 'JSON',
                'rest_data' => $json
                );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postArgs);

// Make the REST call, returning the result
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (!$response) {
    die("Connection Failure.\n");
}

// Convert the result from JSON format to a PHP array
$result = json_decode($response);
if ( !is_object($result) ) {
    die("Error handling result.\n");
}
if ( !isset($result->module_name) ) {
    die("Error: {$result->name} - {$result->description}\n.");
}

var_dump($result->module_fields->sales_stage->options);
exit;
```

Comment: thanks John, i wasn't aware of the options under the modulefield

Comment: one quick question john, does this list values(names) remain same for every installation of sugarcrm ?

Comment: Yes it does. And it will also return localized strings if applicable